# Why is UIImage rotated after being initialised from asssets?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, assets

I have an image in my `xcassets` folder which is in `PDF` format and I init and assign to an `UIImageView` this way:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "myImage", in: Bundle.current, compatibleWith: nil)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

When I run the app, this image is displayed rotated/flip, but I'm not rotating it in code. The image file looks ok. What could it be happening there?

Comment: Please add screenshots which shows actual and expected output.

Comment: @Bhaumik I'm not able to take a screenshot at this moment, but the image is displayed mirrored.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which is completely ununderstandable. But it only happened to a tiny rectangular vector image oriented vertically, placed in xcassets. I tried a few things like changing all the settings xcasset gives us. Alas, the only thing that worked for me was to increase the image size. Then iOS stopped changing the orientation.

It really looks like a bug from xcode trying to compress/optimize images and mistakenly rotate images...

Anyway, try to change the image size (scale it up - or insert margins). Also, try to export to another media type.